# Twilio SMS queued but not delivered, getting Error code : 30005

Tags: node.js, api, twilio

I am getting Error code 30005 while sending SMS using Twilio node js. Also getting Status: queued but on checking on Twilio logs then the Undelivered status is there.

Comment: Possible reasons are explained on : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30005

Comment: already referred this link but not working for me. Is there any number format issue with Indian numbers or can anyone provide a sample node js program for this?

Comment: Please go through the guidelines for sending SMS in India https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in (By Twilio). Make sure your integration supports SMS to DND numbers. Please go through the TRAI regulations with respect to SMS in India on https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/trai-regulations.

Comment: Can you share request/ response/logs? so if there is something wrong with that then we can figure it out.

Comment: var twilioNumber = '+1XXXXXXXXXX';
var twilioSID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var twilioToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

var client = require('twilio')(twilioSID, twilioToken);

var sendSMS = function (number, ttt) {
messages.create({
number,
twilioNumber,
body: ttt
}, function (err, text) {
if (err) {
console.log('err: ' + err);
} else {
console.log('Sent: ' + text.body);
console.log('Status: ' + text.status);
}
});
};

sendSMS('+91 XXX XXX XXXX', 'Hi there, this is test message');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Indian mobile numbers by default DND services are enabled and if we want to send SMS through Twilio then we have to contact Twilio person to enable for activate the different plan for sending SMS. They will ask for some details for activating services with the new plan.